# Powerpoint Visual Basic Save as Picture

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to save as picture the active slide I'm working on using VB in Powerpoint. 
This code works fine, but only with the slide number (1) and if all images and shapes are selected, how could I do to select all the objects on the active slide (like CTRL + A) and then export it as an picture?

```
Sub Export_Image()

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Select
Call ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Export( _
"C:\ARTES\CRETA.png", ppShapeFormatPNG, 1500, 1500, ppRelativeToSlide)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`Slide.Export`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.export).

```
Sub ExportImage()
    ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Export FileName:="C:\ARTES\CRETA.png", _
                                   FilterName:="PNG", _
                                   ScaleWidth:=1500, _
                                   ScaleHeight:=1500
End Sub
```